# How to account for dependencies in survival analysis of PS-matched cohorts with replacement?

Tags: survival, propensity-scores, matching, kaplan-meier

I work on data from a cohort study (n = 3100). We want to compare outcomes of individuals with a special condition (n = 300) and their matched controls.
I estimated propensity scores and used genetic matching in order to create a 2:1-matched data set. Because baseline covariates are quite imbalanced, I turned to matching with replacement, which led to much better post-matching balance of covariates.

Now, I want to perform survival-analysis using the Kaplan-Meier-Estimator. My question is: How do I account for the fact, that multiple control subjects are used several times in the control group? Simply put, can I draw "normal" KM-plots using all the "duplicates" in the control group? I know one has to factor in the weights assigned to these control subjects when calculating treatment effects. What I don't understand, however, how one is supposed to account for these dependencies when performing survival analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly identify, one needs to account for both the pairing and the repeated use of the control units to validly account for all sources of dependence. [Austin & Cafri (2020)](http://doi.org/10.1002/sim.8502) explain how to do so and provide R code for their variance estimator.

(Note: the R code is in the supplementary files. After downloading the file, change the file ending to .pdf to open the file)